# how to do hedge calculation in jquery on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Please check the screenshot for more clear]

[**Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/cosvmw8m/1/)

I'm trying to program a hedging finance formula. I did statically, how can I do it dynamically ?

If I give the amount the calculation wants to do it automatically like

If I give amount as "Amount - 7000"

```
++--A--++--B--
5500  Amount- col A = 5500
Col B(5500) - col A(875) = 4625
Col B(4625) - col A(658) = 3967
```

This is what's happening. How do I do this dynamically in jQuery ?

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Amountvalue = $('#Amountvalue').val();
   // var CurrencyBought = $('#CurrencyBought').val();

    $('.Amountvalue').keyup(function(){
     var CurrencyBought =  $('.CurrencyBought122').val();
     var Finalvalue  = parseInt($(this).val())-CurrencyBought;
             $('#Result345').val(Finalvalue);
    });

});
```

Comment: FYI, even it works, `$('document')` should be `$(document)`

Comment: sorry :( that was an typo mistake @A.Wolff

Comment: `var Finalvalue  = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) - parseInt(CurrencyBought, 10);`

Comment: what should it do @LShetty did u understand my question ?

Comment: What's currently broken in your fiddle link? When I use it #result345 fills out correctly on keyup.

Comment: i need fill out on all other fields how can i do it ?

Comment: @ Question User i could not understand your formula`amount = 1000`, `a1=1500`,`a2=875`,`a3=658`,`a4=157`,`a5=247` what are you expected `b1=?`,`b2=?`,`b3=?`,`b4=?`,`b5=?`

Comment: check the posted answer @ozil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Use $(".selector").each() to loop on your inputs

```
$('[id="Result"]').each(function(){
            Finalvalue -= parseInt($(this).val());
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.Result').val(Finalvalue);
        })
```

and this is my demo [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cosvmw8m/3/)